# Does this proof that $\mathbb{D}$ is countable work?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that the set $\mathbb{D}$ of finite decimals is countable. My proof seems too simple to work out - I simply list the all of the decimals with $N$ digits for all $N\geq 1$, starting with $N=1$ and working up from there.

It seems like I would reach every single decimal eventually and end up with a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, as there are only a finite number of decimals with $N$ digits. Does this proof work?

Comment: Essentially yes.

Comment: How many digits does $12.34$ have?

Comment: Do you mean numbers  **between 0 and 1**?  That would avoid Ingix's point.  If not first prove it for numbers between 0 and 1 and then use the fact that there is a one to one mapping of "numbers between 0 and 1" and "numbers between n and n+1" for any integer, n.

Comment: $12.34$ would have 4 digits in this case, but wouldn't the proof still work since even if you can shift the decimal around, there's still a finite number of decimals in each set of decimals of length n?

Comment: $\mathbb D\subset\mathbb Q$

Comment: As John is pointing out, it is essentially $\frac n{10^k}$ for $(n,k)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb N$ so it injects in $\mathbb N^3$ (considering the usual injection of Z in N²), thus countable.